# is there a standard array with fixed buffer item and dynamic item count?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, containers, std

I am looking for a standard container in C++98 (not in C++11)
Which would have this spec : 
- fixed buffer size (like a simple array)
- with a count accessor (like vector)

Here is kind of what i am looking for :

```
template <class TYPE, size_t ARRAY_SIZE>
  class Array
  {
    /*-------------------------------- MEMBERS ---------------------------------*/
    private:
      TYPE     _array[ARRAY_SIZE];
      size_t   _count;
    /*--------------------- CONSTRUCTORS/DESTRUCTORS ---------------------------*/
    public:
      Array():_count(0){}

    /*------------------------------- METHODS ----------------------------------*/

    public:
      inline const TYPE * data() const {return _array;}
      inline void clear() {_count= 0; }
      inline void push_back(const TYPE& i_type) {_array[_count] = i_type; _count++;}
      inline size_t count() const {return _count;}
      inline size_t max_size() const {return ARRAY_SIZE;}
      inline bool empty() const {return (_count== 0);}
      const TYPE& operator[](size_t i_index){return _array[i_index];}
  };
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be fixed size, as opposed to simply creating it at a given size and never growing it?  Do you need to know the size at compile-time?  If so, why?

Comment: If `vector` is not acceptable (why not?), all C++98 offers are C-style arrays, which _are_ fixed buffer size, and which have a size function in the form `sizeof(array)/sizeof(T)`. C++11 has a proper class for fixed-size arrays (and there is probably no reason why you couldn't just copy the header and so some minor fixup so it's standalone).

Comment: There are 2 reasons why i need this kind of container. 1) it's for embedded software so i prefer that all memory is initialized at startup so i'll be sure that there'll be enough memory for all scenarios. 2) this kind of container allow me to put it in a class that i can send as message to an other process, if the other process have same message's class definition i can just cast the buffer into that type of class and handle the message.

Comment: @rastafaryd I edited my answer to provide a link to one implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. Nor is it really viable to manipulate allocators into doing so for `vector`. You can write your own, or find one in some third party library.

Boost.Container's [static_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.static_vector) might be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Within `push_back(const TYPE& i_type) {_array[_count] = i_type; _count++;}` and `operator []` you should check whether you are crossing the boundary, then either ignore or throw appropriate exception like ArrayIndexOutOfBounds kind of.

Use `std::vector`, why reinvent the same wheel?

Answer (score 0):

This may be considered by some to be antithetical to good C++, but given the constraints and presumed requirements (including needing to know the size at compile time), I would consider using a simple C-style array.

Just as there is a place for macros and other constructs considered Evil in C++, there is also a place for C-arrays.  It's not the tool that's evil, but how it's used.

If you don't need to know the siae at compile-time, then I would lean towards using a `vector`, sizing it correctly up front and simply never growing it.